# C#: Move Controls From Form to tabPage in VS Form Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2005, windows-forms-designer

I decided to change a utility I'm working on to use a tabpage.  When I tried to drag various controls from the form to a tab page on top of the form, it made copies of the control, giving it a different name.  It's easy enough to just remake the form on top of the tab or just edit the source code in the designer to have everything be added to the tab instead (and this is what I did, which worked), but it seems like there would probably be a better way to do this via the gui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried cut and paste.  That usually works for me.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but for some reason that makes no sense whatsoever, I decided not to.

Comment: For me, cut-and-paste has the **unacceptable** side affect of removing all of the Event Handler hookups for the controls being moved. Document Outline keeps them intact. Robert Venables should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Cut and paste does not bring over the event hooks. They must be manually re-attached. Very do-able but also very tedious and error prone. I recommend the Document Outline. ref Robert Venables' entry

Answer (score 24):

The correct tool for this is the Document Outline (CTRL+W, U). Simply drag your set of controls in the outline so that they are under the tab page. Voila.

The document outline dramatically simplifies these types of operations, especially when you are dealing with complex layouts.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but your answer is correct. After ruining a whole form by using Cut/Paste and severing all the code, I tried the Document Outline (CTRL+ALT+T in VS2010) and it all worked like a breeze!

Comment: The problem with Document Outline is that you can only move one control at a time.

Comment: Update: VS 2017

View >> Other Windows >> Document Outline (Ctrl + Alt + T)

Answer (score 0):

Your control key is stuck. Do not press control key when dragging controls.

I drag controls from form control to tab page controls all the time no problem. Answer #1 is totally correct.

You can use the Document Outline window and move the controls to the tab page one by one by dragging tree nodes.

The hardest problem is retaining control locations on the tab page.

Comment: If the controls are all logically grouped together, hopefully they are on a panel and you can move the whole panel through the Document Outline window. This maintains position in the new location.